# OpenCV keypoint "response" values all 0 for SIFT feature detector

Tags: opencv, sift

I am instantiating a SIFT FeatureDetector and trying to detect keypoints on certain image with a corresponding mask. I get good keypoints within the mask, however, these feature keypoints are not ranked in any order. All the response values for the keypoints are zero. Does anyone know why this would be, or what I might be missing?

EDIT:
Sample Code. Of course the keypoints, mask and image variables have been initialized already.

```
Ptr<FeatureDetector> detector = FeatureDetector::create("SIFT"); //new SiftFeatureDetector();                      

detector->detect(loadedImg, keypoints_free, mask);
```

Comment: Could you show some sample code?

Comment: How would you like them to be ranked?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found this bug-entry: http://code.opencv.org/issues/2210

It says that this bug is fixed in openCV 2.4.4.